# Module cwd assistance

Tags: linux, perl, cwd

I created a Perl module that is to be used in many Perl scripts to use [`Net::SSH::Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect)
to do a login.

```
package myRoutines;
#
use v5.22;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSH::Expect;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(my_login);

sub my_login {
    my $user         = 'xxxx';
    my $port         = '10000';
    my $passwd       = 'XYZ';
    my $adminServer  = 'myServer';
    my $rootpassword = 'ABCDEF';

    my ( $pName, $vName ) = @_;

    our $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
        host       => "$adminServer",
        ssh_option => "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null",
        user       => "$user",
        password   => "$passwd",
        port       => "$port",
        raw_pty    => 1,
        restart_timeout_upon_receive => 1,
        log_file                     => "/var/tmp/clilog_$pName$vName"
    );

    eval {

        my $login_output = $ssh->login();

        if ( $login_output !~ />/ ) {
            die "Login has failed.
              Login output was $login_output";
        }
    };

    return $ssh;
}

1;
```

The scripts will do:

```
use myRoutines qw(my_login);

our ( $ssh, $pName, $vName );

$pName = 'abc';
$vName = '123';

$ssh = my_login( $pName, $vName );

$ssh->send( "some command\r" );
```

This all works if I'm in the directory that the script and module are in. If I'm in any other directory, the `new` call works but the call to `$ssh->send` does nothing.

I've tried adding to my script:

```
use lib '/some/dir';
```

(where the .pm file resides) to force it find the module, and that seems to work when I'm not in the directory where the pm file resides.

I've tried to:

```
use File::chdir;
$CWD = '/some/dir';
```

and again, the login seems to work but the next send does nothing. So I'm at a loss as to what might be happening and would like some advice.

Update 20170908:

Upon further playing and following the suggestions made, I've done the following and it now works:

removed the eval as it was unnecessary.
removed the our's and made it my's.
removed the ""'s

set the following in the script:

```
use File::Basename;
use Cwd qw( abs_path );
chdir "/some/dir";
use lib dirname(abs_path($0));
my $scriptName = basename($0);
use myRoutines qw(ovm_login);
my $pName = substr($scriptName,0,-3);   (cutting off the .pl from the end of the script name to pass the scriptname as the pName)
```

using chdir to change directory to where my pl script and pm file is and then setting the lib is seemingly working as it should.

Borodin, I'm not sure I understand your meaning when you say to object orient the module and .... but would be interested in hearing more to better understand.

Comment: Why the `eval` and `die` inside it? Why `our` and not `my`?

Comment: It would be tidier to make this an object-oriented module that subclassed `Net::SSH::Expect` rather than just a function library. But you've done everything right with `Exporter` and that's unusual; well done.

Comment: Although I don't understand how, it sounds like the module file is being found successfully in both cases (otherwise `use myRoutines` would fail). Have you found out why the `send` method call is failing? Is there a stray `myRoutines.pm` in the other directory you're running from? If `some command` generates output then you should use `read_all`or `read_line` to see any errors, or you can just use `exec` instead of `send`.

Comment: You should remove the `eval`, as it's preventing you from seeing any errors from the `login` call.

Comment: `host => "$adminServer"` etc. should be `host => $adminServer`. The quotes are unnecessary at best, and may cause problems in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hardcode the directory, you can use

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

(`$RealBin` is the path to the script. Adjust as needed if `myRoutines.pm` is in a subdir.)

Answer (score -2):

The simple and easy way would be placing your `.pm` file in:
 `/usr/lib64/perl5/`
directory and you shouldn't have any problems.
But still not the perfect solution, you should be able to put the `.pm` file wherever you want.